# Azure devops and semantic release

Tags: semantic-release

I'm new to using semantic release and trying to integrate it into azure devops but I keep running in to problems.
The command I'm trying to run is:
npx -p semantic-release@22.0.12 -p @semantic-release/commit-analyzer -p @semantic-release/changelog -p @semantic-release/git -p @semantic-release/release-notes-generator -p @semantic-release/exec semantic-release -d --branches DEVGJN

The result is that I end up with a couple of error, I've been searching the internet how the fix this but can't find a good answer.
Can someone please help this newbie?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY9k8.png)

My main questions are:
Why is it asking for a github token when I'm using Azure devops (git)
Why do I need a package.json.